# Can't login to VM SharePoint 2016 from the network

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication, user-accounts, windows-server, domain

I set up a virtual demo environment for a single SharePoint 2016 farm. I followed the steps on this open guide: https://github.com/CriticalPathTraining/SharePoint2016VmSetupGuide

What it's achieved is creating a Single Windows 2016 Server with:

- DNS and Active Directory set up with a group of Server users (to configure and run SharePoint), and a group of users to test it. The Domain is ***wingtip.com***
- SQL Server 2016 Trial and two instances: WINGTIPSERVER and WINGTIPSERVER\SHAREPOINT
- Internal network interface with IP 192.168.150.1 and pointing DNS to self (127.0.0.1). I configured this adapter as bridged, so it's still connected to the physical network
- External network interface (bridge and connected to the physical network) with IP assigned by DHCP. E.g. 10.131.69.69.
- SharePoint 2016 with:

  - **User Profile Service Application** Active and a Synchronisation connection set up so that all the Users in the Wingtip User group are synchronised with SharePoint

[image]

- Firewall is disabled

The current problem that I have is that **only WINGTIP\Administrator can access the site collection**, and only if accessing the site collection from the server.

I created another VM with Windows 10. Tried to ping the server and although the internal (192.168.150.1 is not accessible), it does respond to external 10.131.69.69. If I set this Windows VM to use 10.131.69.69 as primary DNS, and then try to join wingtip.com with one of the users, e.g. WINGTIP\DavidM it works fine, and joins the domain, but when I try to open the site https://intranet.wingtip it just shows this:

[image]

This is a fragment of what I found in the logs (trying to access the search site (similar issue):

```
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...tpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper...  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           User Key                        ayswq   Medium      Successfully got user key for user. UserNameSuffix: '0#.w|wingtip\davidm'.  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    a7r50   Medium      RunWithElevated:    baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           User Key                        ayswq   Medium      Successfully got user key for user. UserNameSuffix: '0#.w|wingtip\davidm'.  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    a7r50   Medium      RunWithElevated:    baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         azrx9   Medium      LookupHostHeaderSite: Using site lookup provider Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabaseSiteLookupProvider for host-header site-based multi-url lookup string http://search.wingtip.com for request Uri http://search.wingtip.com/. baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      a0n3e   Medium      Entering Monitored Scope (SPConfigurationDatabaseSiteLookupProvider.ISPSiteLookupProviderHostHeaderMultiUrl.LookupHostHeaderSiteIdAndZone). Parent=Request (GET:http://search.wingtip.com/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http://search.wingtip.com&correlation=b9adf69d-b8a2-60bc-e376-1fd62f32e471)  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      a0n3e   Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope: (SPConfigurationDatabaseSiteLookupProvider.ISPSiteLookupProviderHostHeaderMultiUrl.LookupHostHeaderSiteIdAndZone) Execution Time=0.897288044080014; CPU Milliseconds=0; SQL Query Count=1; Parent=Request (GET:http://search.wingtip.com/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http://search.wingtip.com&correlation=b9adf69d-b8a2-60bc-e376-1fd62f32e471)  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         adyrv   High        Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri http://search.wingtip.com/.    baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     avwhw   Medium      SPRequestModule.ErrorAppHandler Begin   baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      Application error when access /_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx, Error=The Web application at http://search.wingtip.com could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri&... baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      ... primaryUri)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AccessRequestsDialog.<>c__DisplayClass2.<OnLoad>b__1()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AccessRequestsDialog.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System....  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      ...Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at http://search.wingtip.com could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri)     at Microsoft.Shar... baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...ePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AccessRequestsDialog.<>c__DisplayClass2.<OnLoad>b__1()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AccessRequestsDialog.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    ...  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ... at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        Getting Error Message for Exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at http://search.wingtip.com could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, U... baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...ri& primaryUri)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AccessRequestsDialog.<>c__DisplayClass2.<OnLoad>b__1()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AccessRequestsDialog.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at Syst...  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...em.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            aw5fv   Medium      SPOIncidentsDetectionJob.UpdateErrorTextsIfNeeded: About to call GetSPOIncidentBitStatus    baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            aw5f0   Medium      SPOIncidentsDetectionJob.GetSPOIncidentBitStatus: Just entered this method. baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            aw5f1   Medium      SPOIncidentsDetectionJob.GetSPOIncidentBitStatus: spoIncidentJob is non null.   baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            aubgp   High        SPOIncidentsDetectionJob.GetSPOIncidentBitStatus: spoIncidentJob was null. Accessing the cached bit of the SPOIncidentsDetectionJob baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            aw5fz   Medium      SPOIncidentsDetectionJob.UpdateErrorTextsIfNeeded: Some exception in this method.   baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            aubgn   Monitorable SPOIncidentsDetectionJob.UpdateErrorTextsIfNeeded: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.     at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPOIncidentsDetectionJob.GetSPOIncidentBitStatus()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPOIncidentsDetectionJob.UpdateErrorTextsIfNeeded(String& errorText, String& linkText, String& linkUrl, Boolean& shouldIgnoreLinkValidation)  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aat87   Monitorable     baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8xfr    Medium      PermissionMask check failed for {79C9145B-EE0A-4AF8-A24E-07E3AE3F89EC}. Asking for 0x00010000, have 0x00000000  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e2s    Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aix9j   High        SPRequest.OpenWeb: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-3918793598-2166099872-3631999646-1125, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://search.wingtip.com/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http://search.wingtip.com&correlation=b9adf69d-b8a2-60bc-e376-1fd62f32e471    baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_EnableMinimalDownload()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.P... baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...rocessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPageInternal(String message, String linkText, String linkUrl, Int32 statusCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.ErrorHandler(HttpApplication app, Boolean errorIsOnErrorPage)     at Microsoft.Sh...  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...arePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.ErrorAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.RecordError(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr ...  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8xfr    Medium      PermissionMask check failed for {79C9145B-EE0A-4AF8-A24E-07E3AE3F89EC}. Asking for 0x00010000, have 0x00000000  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e2s    Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aix9j   High        SPRequest.OpenWeb: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-3918793598-2166099872-3631999646-1125, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://search.wingtip.com/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http://search.wingtip.com&correlation=b9adf69d-b8a2-60bc-e376-1fd62f32e471    baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_EnableMinimalDownload()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.P... baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...rocessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPageInternal(String message, String linkText, String linkUrl, Int32 statusCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.ErrorHandler(HttpApplication app, Boolean errorIsOnErrorPage)     at Microsoft.Sh...  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...arePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.ErrorAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.RecordError(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr ...  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           General                         agxkz   High        calling GetCurrentGenericSetupPath for a versioned path: TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS   baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     avwh5   Medium      SPRequestModule.PreSendRequestHeaders End   baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.19  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     avwhx   Medium      SPRequestModule.ErrorAppHandler End baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.20  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  Web Content Management          Publishing                      aytib   Medium      ObjectCachePerRequest Global:False, Enabled:False   baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.20  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     avwia   Medium      SPRequestModule.PostLogRequestHandler Begin baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.20  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     avwib   Medium      SPRequestModule.PostLogRequestHandler End   baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.20  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     avwic   Medium      SPRequestModule.EndRequestHandler Begin baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.20  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 avwhy,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 az4z8,0 nasq,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 az4z8,0 avwhz,0 aytib,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 a7r51,0 a1n25,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 a9fy7,0 a9fy6,0 b4ly,0 b4ly,0 bjvyg,0 avwh6,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 az4z8,0 agb9s,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 ajd6k,0 ajd6l,0 ajd6m,0 b4ly,0 avwh7,0 avwh8,0 avwh0,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 ayswq,0 a0t92,0 a08yd,0 a0t94,0 a0t97,0 a0t98,1 ayswq,4 az4z8,0 b4ly,0 avwh1,0 aj1kn,0 avwh2,0 avwh3,0 avwhu,0 avwhv,77 aix9j,0 ai1wu,0 aix9j,0 ai1wu,0 ... baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.20* w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      ...ayswq,0 a7r50,0 ayswq,0 a7r50,0 azrx9,0 a0n3e,0 a0n3e,0 adyrv,0 avwhw,0 8nca,0 tkau,0 ajlz0,0 aw5fv,0 aw5f0,0 aw5f1,0 aubgp,0 aw5fz,0 aubgn,0 aat87,0 aix9j,0 ai1wu,0 aix9j,0 ai1wu,0 agxkz,1 avwh5,0 avwhx,0 aytib,0 avwia,0 avwib,0 avwic  baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.20  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         aoxsq   Medium      Sending HTTP response 200 for HTTP request GET to http://search.wingtip.com/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http://search.wingtip.com&correlation=b9adf69d-b8a2-60bc-e376-1fd62f32e471 baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.20  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope: (Request (GET:http://search.wingtip.com/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http://search.wingtip.com&correlation=b9adf69d-b8a2-60bc-e376-1fd62f32e471)) Execution Time=109.180205297016; CPU Milliseconds=27; SQL Query Count=16; Parent=None    baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
05/30/2017 10:27:49.20  w3wp.exe (0x1B54)                           0x4638  SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     avwid   Medium      SPRequestModule.EndRequestHandler End   baadf69d-8826-60bc-e376-1feded9d39aa
```

Comment: it seems an issue in configuring Alternative Access Mapping, could you please share your current setting, also take a look at https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/26/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/